# MVC Reports print business cards

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, asp.net-mvc-5, report, rdlc

I have the need to print business cards in my asp mvc project. In my project I have a table of persons and I need to print a business card for all users in my table.

The Ideia is to print all the records at the same time and set the users information on the business card. For example: if my table person has 10 users then when I press the print button I need to have 10 business cards each card with it´s on information (User Information).

I started by creating a printcard.rdlc in my project but when I press the print button the report does not display all business cards. It only shows **1 business** card when I need it to **show all business cards** at the same time. A business card for each user registed in my person table.
Here is a picture that I hope that will help me to explain what I need:

[image]

[image]

etc...

This problem that I am having is I have a table of 20 Users and when I click on the print button insted of apearing 20 Business Cards in that report only apears One report card.

I need it to show the 20 Business Cards ate once so that I can print that report it prints all the users at once.

How can I go about this?

Comment: This is not enough information. No one can understand your question.

Comment: Hello. I have change the question. Thank's